# Is it possible to obtain a torus by gluing 2 Möbius bands?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, transformation, mobius-band

[image]

Is this transform actually possible? Which is gluing edges of two Mobius bands to make a torus? I tried to do it physically with pieces of paper, but I couldn't complete it. The detailed explanation and image reference is in [here](http://web1.kcn.jp/hp28ah77/us27i_pape.htm), at figure 19.

Comment: have you seen (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1036755) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I've seen it now, but still I'm confused. Are you implying that it is impossible to achieve the upper process with a piece of paper?

Comment: The torus is orientable, so cannot contain a non-orientable submanifold of the same dimension. In particular, the torus cannot contain a Mobius band.